# Haskell: errors when trying to define function with two arguments

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to define a simple function that turns a list of single integers into one larger integer. For example, given the list [1,5,2,0] it would return 1520.
To do that in base 10 I used:

```
calc_nr [] = 0
calc_nr (a:y) = a * 10^(length y) + (calc_nr y)
```

Now, I wanted to extend that to different bases, which can be done by altering the base 10 power in the expression to the desired base. For that, I thought of taking in another argument, b, and replacing the base 10 power for a base b power.
However, I'm getting some errors when I try to do that. Writing:

```
calc_nr b [] = 0
calc_nr b (a:y) = a * b^(length y) + (calc_nr y)
```

Gives me the error:

```
* Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: t ~ [t]
  Expected type: [t] -> t
    Actual type: t -> [t] -> t
* Relevant bindings include
    calc_nr :: [t] -> t (bound at calc_nr.hs:39:1)
```

I'm new to Haskell, so maybe this is quite a stupid mistake, but any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, some general advice:

- **Always write type signatures** for top-level functions. This has plenty of advantages (more on that later), but perhaps the most important is that somebody reading your code will understand what it's supposed to do. Your old fixed-base-10 function would be

  ```
  fromBase10rep :: [Int] -> Int
  ```

  (You could also make it generic to work with other number types apart from `Int`, but I won't go into that to keep it simple.)
- Avoid unnecessary parentheses.

  ```
  fromBase10Rep (a:y) = a * 10 ^ length y + calc_nr y
  ```
- Avoid `length` and indexing into lists. This is inefficient (the entire list needs to be traversed every time you do it).

If you just follow the first point, you'll probably be able to answer the question yourself...

```
fromBaseRep :: Int -> [Int] -> Int
fromBaseRep b [] = 0
fromBaseRep b (a:y) = a * b ^ length y + fromBaseRep y
```

because, thanks to the type signature, the compiler is now able to give a much clearer error message:

```
/tmp/wtmpf-file21653.hs:3:42: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Int’
                  with actual type ‘[Int] -> Int’
    • Probable cause: ‘fromBaseRep’ is applied to too few arguments
      In the second argument of ‘(+)’, namely ‘fromBaseRep y’
      In the expression: a * b ^ length y + fromBaseRep y
      In an equation for ‘fromBaseRep’:
          fromBaseRep b (a : y) = a * b ^ length y + fromBaseRep y
  |
3 | fromBaseRep b (a:y) = a * b ^ length y + fromBaseRep y
  |                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Basically it tells you exactly what the problem is: you've applied `fromBaseRep` to too few arguments in the recursive call. It still needs to know which base to recompose the rest of the number in!

So just pass it `b` again, and you'll be fine.

```
fromBaseRep b (a:y) = a * b ^ length y + fromBaseRep b y
```

As I said, this is still really inefficient due to the `length` call. A good way to get around this is to multiply out the left digits while recursing deeper into the list:

```
fromBaseRep b = go 0
 where go acc [] = acc
       go acc (a:y) = go (b*acc + a) y
```

Note that delegating the recursion to a local “loop function” `go` also allowed me to omit explicitly passing on `b` – it's simply re-used from the `fromBaseRep b = ...` binding.

This can also be written elegantly as a fold:

```
fromBaseRep b = foldl' ((+) . (b*)) 0
```

Comment: I really wish GHC would take a leaf out of Elm's playbook and put  `Probable cause: ‘fromBaseRep’ is applied to too few arguments` front and centre.

Comment: @SwiftsNamesake Well, sometimes that advice from GHC is a red herring, so GHC prefers to mention first the certain issue, and then follow with a probable cause.

Comment: Indeed. Also, I have a few time seen a “probable cause” of `function foo is applied to 2 arguments, but its type ... has only 3`.

Comment: That's just a *bad* message then. Which should be fixed. In general, GHC errors could be a lot better imo.